# "As such,he helped saved 6 lives..." What grammar category

Tags: relative-clauses, past-participles, bare-infinitive, such

I need help in identifying the grammar category. Why is Past Participle used after the word "helped" and what grammar category to refer to understand?
"*In August 2017, Elijah Mayhew, 15, of Florida died of a gunshot wound there.Weeks earlier, he had told his mom that he wanted to be an organ donor. ****As such, he helped saved**** six lives, including one chronicled in the Journal Star, part of the USA TODAY Network"*

Comment: It's a typographic error. It should be _he helped save six lives_.

Comment: Writers often insert words as alternatives: *helped save?* or *saved?*. Being human, they then forget to remove the unwanted choice, and editors occasionally let the typo slip through. Big oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this is an error. I have never found it ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=helped+save%2Chelped+saved&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelped%20save%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chelped%20saved%3B%2Cc0)).

However, it appears that from about the turn of century people have begun to write that and so, presumably, they've begun to use it in everyday speech some little time before that. Quite a few books written in the period I mention show this form: [ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22helped%20saved%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en). At least 50 books show that form. From an examination of all occurrences it is clear that the form has been used a lot with a separating comma (helped, saved) and there is even a case of "helped/saved". It is clear from that this otherwise ungrammatical form is a verbal form introducing what you could call binary verbs. However, it is not clear that "helped and saved" is an equivalent, as it would be for "helped, saved". This is probably an American linguistic invention and there is no guarantee it will be successful even in America. Personally I wouldn't use it.

Comment: If we put a comma in the sentence, it would not create a non-defining relative clause  "As such, he helped, saved six lives.."  as it is not suitable/reasonable to define "As such" with "he helped"?

Comment: @AnfisaIbragimova For a relative defining clause or as well for a non defining one you need a pronoun (which, that, …); you are not concerned with that then. It's really equivalent to a coordination when you use a comma.